# How to create shares in a cluster with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing

We are moving our File server into a failover cluster.  There are quite some shares to set up again.  Is it possible to create them with Powershell?

I found the `New-SmbShare` cmdlet, but I don't see how I can use it for a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

-ScopeName  is the needed parameter.

Make sure your Path is on a disk made available in the same cluster role as provided to ScopeName.

```
    New-SmbShare -name 'ShareName' -ScopeName "ClusterRoleName" -Path "N:\SHARE\"
```

Answer (score 0):

The New-SmbShare provides access to your file system folder for other remote clients as a Server Message Block  Share. 
 Simply specify the path to the cluster storage as a parameter to New-SmbShare.

See Microsoft docs on SmbShare: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbshare?view=win10-ps

Comment: yeah, I can indeed use New-SmbShare locally from the File server.  I keep having trouble with our Security groups, though. They contain spaces, and they don't get mapped to the correct group by the cmdlet.